# Kernel Not Installing

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, kernel, software-installation

I followed the exact steps from [here](https://devmultipathtcp.wordpress.com/2015/05/15/install-the-mptcp-kernel/) and installed MPTCP Kernel on Ubuntu 14.04 on a system. I had to reinstall Ubuntu due to some reasons, the same 14.04 version and now when I follow the steps I can't install the kernel i.e. even after the reboot, uname -r shows the kernel version 3.16 and not the mptcp kernel.

Is it that the kernel which was used by Ubuntu 14.04 changed ? Or could there be some other possible causes because the steps in the linked worked entirely the previous time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub always boots with the latest kernel by default.

Ubuntu 14.04 had 3.13 kernel, you installed kernel 3.14 and the systems booted with 3.14.

Ubuntu 14.04.2 has 3.16 kernel. That is higher that 3.14 and the system boots with 3.16.

You can go to boot menu bu pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> at boot and boot with the desired kernel.

To make this permanent you can remove standard Ubuntu kernels image and headers using `synaptic` and also remove meta packages `linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` and `linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic`.

You will always boot with the custom kernel.

Comment: Is there any way I can make the change persistent, I want to boot with the mptcp kernel only every time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @adrian008 I added that. You need to remove Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: Thanks, could you also give some links (that you think could be helpful, I am a novice) to remove the standard Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: @adrian008 Install Synaptic and remove `linux-image` and `linux-headers` packages with version 3.16.

Comment: @adrian008 But first try to boot with your custom kernel. Otherwise you can remove all working kernels.

Comment: Yes, custom kernel is working, I booted and then am accessing my PC. I will understand how it is removed fully before removing it. Also, is there any possibility that some programs or software that earlier worked with 3.16 will not work with the 3.14 mptcp kernel, which only has a different version of transport layer protocol ?

Comment: That's very unlikely.